# TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str , when trying to create a dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7

im interfacing with an INfoblox api,

here is what the data looks like ..

```
[
{
    "_ref": "network/ZG5zLm5ldHdvcmskMTAuMTAwLjIyOC4wLzI0LzA:10.100.228.0/24/default", 
    "comment": "jacksonville - mgmt", 
    "network": "10.100.228.0/24", 
    "network_view": "default"
}, 
{
    "_ref": "network/ZG5zLm5ldHdvcmskMTAuMTAwLjIxLjAvMjQvMA:10.100.21.0/24/default", 
    "comment": "miami - mgmt", 
    "network": "10.100.21.0/24", 
    "network_view": "default"
}]
```

here is my code

```
def foo():
    r = session.get(url + 'network', params={'_max_results': str(5000)})
    z = r.json()
    return dict((h['comment'], h['network']) for h in r.content)
    #return r.content
```

im getting the error "TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str" when executing the function above.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to use `z`:

```
return dict((h['comment'], h['network']) for h in z)
```

Comment: now im getting a KeyError: 'comment' , can a dictionary be made of above? or should each network be a dictionary ?

Comment: @wwi: then your data is not what you have posted.